# bspwm on cygwin - slow redraw isssue

Tags: cygwin, rxvt, bspwm

I have managed to compile bspwm tiling window manager under cygwin 2.10.0(0.325/5/3) (Windows 7), compared to Openbox, LXDE or fwvm the performance is quite bad. Can you please suggest me some ideas how to troubleshoot this problem?

From time to time I need to test some linux bash scripts and commands under windows and I need multiple terminal windows. Having it boxed in one window in bspwm would be very convenient and would allow me to set up my terminal workspace as needed.

**Symptoms:**

- Slow redraw speed while scrolling in terminal(urxvt) via Shift + PgUp or PgDown
- Terminator is a bit faster but typing is quite laggy.
- Commands for node switching, jumping between desktops etc are executed with ~300 ms delay (just a guess). That is quite small but it makes the workflow feel unpleasant.

Some apps take time to start even under Openbox or Fvwm but the gui respone is fast and urxvt is lighting fast even when running big vim files etc.

**For the start this is my XWin start log:**

```
Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.19.6.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 CZCHOWN5022406 2.10.0(0.325/5/3) 2018-02-02 15:16 x86_64
OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (Win64)
Package: version 1.19.6-2 built 2018-03-12

XWin was started with the following command line:

/usr/bin/X :0 -auth /home/marek/.serverauth.9768 

ddxProcessArgument - Initializing default screens
winInitializeScreenDefaults - primary monitor w 1920 h 1080
winInitializeScreenDefaults - native DPI x 96 y 96
[ 19542.838] (II) xorg.conf is not supported
[ 19542.838] (II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
[ 19542.838] LoadPreferences: /home/marek/.XWinrc not found
[ 19542.838] LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
[ 19542.838] LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
[ 19542.838] winDetectSupportedEngines - RemoteSession: no
[ 19543.087] winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
[ 19543.087] winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005
[ 19543.087] winSetEngine - Using Shadow DirectDraw NonLocking
[ 19543.087] winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
[ 19543.134] winWindowProc - WM_SIZE - new client area w: 1904 h: 1002
[ 19543.150] winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
[ 19543.150] MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
[ 19543.150] XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel
[ 19543.150] (EE) AIGLX: No native OpenGL in modes with a root window
[ 19543.430] (II) IGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[ 19543.446] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[ 19543.446] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[ 19544.054] winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 952 501
[ 19544.054] (--) 5 mouse buttons found
[ 19544.054] (--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
[ 19544.054] (--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 4
[ 19544.054] (--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"
[ 19544.054] (--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
[ 19544.054] Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
[ 19544.725] winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
[ 19544.725] winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
[ 19544.725] OS maintains clipboard viewer chain: yes
[ 19544.741] winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
```

Comment: run under strace to see where is taking too much time. Use cygwin mailing list for X package maintainer support http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin/lists.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowness was caused by a rxvt terminal emulator, especially when it was autostared in a bspwmrc file. I am now using xterm or terminator and bspwm is fast.

I have tried strace to find the reason why, but I did not get any information showing possible problems.